# Get Browser Tab Close event in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, ajax4jsf

I want to get browser tab close event in my JSF page. How can I do this using `<a4j:ajax event="?" .../>` is there any event is JSF ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot directly get browser-tab-close event in `<a4j:ajax event="?" .../>` but there is work around for this

**Step1:** Get tab-close event from javascript like

```
<h:body onunload="tabClosed();">
```

**Step2:** Make JS function and call backing bean like be

```
<h:form>
   <a4j:jsFunction name="tabClosed" action="#{myBean.tabIsClosed()}" ></a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```